# MariaDB 10.0, innodb: Conditional Unique Constraint?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, locking, unique-constraint, mariadb

My schema, simplified:

people:
id (int), name (string), allow_duplicate_name (int)

allow_duplicate_name is 1 for true, 0 for false.

I want to prevent new records from being inserted if their name fields are non-unique, but only if they have allow_duplicate_name == 1. So if we have the following table:

```
id  name  allow_duplicate_name
1   jack  1
2   jack  1
3   ryan  1
4   jack  1
```

Then the following statement should succeed:

```
INSERT INTO people (name, allow_duplicate_name)
VALUES ('jack', 1);
```

But this statement should fail:

```
INSERT INTO people (name, allow_duplicate_name)
VALUES ('jack', 0);
```

My root problem is that I have a race condition where two concurrent transactions both check if a duplicate exists, see that it doesn't, and then insert a new record with the same name and allow_duplicate_name=0.

Another idea I had is to use READ UNCOMMITTED when checking to see if duplicates had been added before committing each transaction, and roll it back instead, letting the application take a different course of action (e.g., pick a new name), since we can tolerate (it would be much less than ideal, but we can handle it...) the race condition where each transaction sees the other and then rolls itself back, but we absolutely cannot allow an insert/update that sets a duplicate name with allow_duplicate_name=0.

I've heard that our setup is such that stored procedures are massive pain to work with, but maybe a stored procedure is the only sane way to solve this?

Comment: When I say that I've heard that stored procedures suck for us, I just mean that the one time I heard a coworker bring it up a while back, the others refused and implied it would be awful. I'm actually not sure what's so special about our setup that makes it bad. It seems like it would be fine to me. >_>

Answer (score 0):

You can almost do what you want. but you'll want to change the name of the variable.  The key idea is that unique indexes allow `NULL` values to be duplicated.  So, when "allow_duplicate_name" is `NULL`, then you can get duplicates.

I would suggest renaming the field to something like `DuplicatesNotAllowed`.  Then create the index:

```
 create unique index idx_people_name_duplicatesnotallowed on people(name, duplciatesnotallowed);
```

You can insert the values as:

```
INSERT INTO people (name, duplciatesnotallowed)
    VALUES ('jack', NULL);
```

This will succeed.

```
INSERT INTO people (name, allow_duplicate_name)
    VALUES ('jack', 1);
```

This will fail the *second* time it is run.  But, if you update the field for the existing rows, then this will fail.  I'm not sure if that meets your needs.

Comment: That doesn't work. If there are any existing people records with name='jack', then

    INSERT INTO people (name, allow_duplicate_name)
    VALUES ('jack', 1);

must fail. It doesn't matter if their allow_duplicate_name field is set to 0, 1, or null - if the record being inserted disallows duplicate names, then it must be prevented from being inserted. Thanks, though!

Comment: Side note: This works in the case of soft deletion : if table has two columns: name and active, the uniq key on name and active will allow insertion when some rows with active as NULL.  Probably it makes more sense to rename original authors table column from `allow_duplicate_name` to `disable_duplication` with ENUM of true and NULL.